# Executables developed in c++ contains Filenames in readable text

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-flags

We develop c++ applications using MSVC2019. Opening the exceutable in a text editor shows filenames of source files with absolute path are embedded in the exe file. How can I get rid of that filenames to hide private data from my local computer (directory structure). This happens also with Release builds.

Comment: Do you include debug info?

Comment: Linker option "Generate debug Info"=No

Comment: You should also disable debug info in the compiler settings.

Comment: I changed compiler setting "Debug Information Format" to None - no change

Comment: @wre Compile without `DEBUG` or `_DEBUG` defined. Do not use `__FILE__` macros for tracing/reporting. You *can* (even *should*) build with debug info, but make sure it's in a separate `.pdb` file, and use [`/pdbaltpath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdbaltpath-use-alternate-pdb-path?view=msvc-160) to strip the full `.pdb` path from the binary. If you still see source paths in the final `.exe`/`.dll` please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the necessary details.